# Self-Hosted WCF - Namespace Reservation required?

Tags: wcf, ssl, self-hosting, netsh

I'm running a Self-Hosted WCF Service (SSL). 
I've seen that other people use netsh to do a namespace
reservation for their Self-Hosted WCF by doing something like that:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

My webservice works without that Namespace Reservation. So is there any
reason to do that? Am I missing something? Why would I do that namespace reservation?

MSDN: [Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're running the code as an administrative user. Any restricted user won't be able to host an HTTP server on port 80, or any port for that matter, without having the URL registered to their account.

See [Why won't my Windows Service that is hosting a WCF Service run under LocalService or NetworkService accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682287/why-wont-my-windows-service-that-is-hosting-a-wcf-service-run-under-localservic), [WCF Service Access right: No access rights to this namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646704/wcf-service-access-right-no-access-rights-to-this-namespace).